# How to campare two date of type string mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, date, mongoose, graphql

I want to get data between two Date 
In my Schema

```
transactionDate : String
```

the function to get data between two date

```
 async getLogsByDate(start, end) {
    return await this.logModel

      .find({ date: { $gte: start, $lte: end } })
      .then((res) => res);
  
  }
```

I use graphql client, Date I passed here is of type String

```
{getLogsByDate(datelogCharts:{start:"2022-03-05",end:"2022-04-05"}) {_id transactionDate} }
```

OUTPUT
I got all dates seems the filter i put doesn't work or I don't know

```
{
  "data": {
    "getLogsByDate": [
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-05"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-06-15"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-05"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-05"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-05"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-05"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-13-05"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
async getLogsByDate(start, end) {
return await this.logModel

  .find({ date: { $gte: new Date(start), $lte: new Date(end) } })
  .then((res) => res);

}
```

As it is of type string, it will not convert to Date. Mongoose is smart but just not that smart.

Comment: {
        "transactionDate": "2022-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "transactionDate": "2022-06-15T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
Still not in the range

Comment: OUTPUT changed but not correct result

Comment: The data says `transactionDate`, why are we filtering with date instead?

`.find({ transactionDate: { $gte: new Date(start), $lte: new Date(end) } })` then.